# Can I insert HTML code in the SQL table, so, when the value is retrieved from that table it will be appropriately formated?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, sql-insert

It might be a silly question, but I have never done something like that.

I created an `sql table` with a description field.

So, the field will contain the bullet pointed data. For example:

> This information is provided for the following reasons:
>
> - The Reason 1 is following.....
> - The Reason 2 is following.....
> - The Reason 3 is following.....

Is that possible to `insert` the data into the table that is bullet point formatted?

Answer (score 0):

You can insert whatever plaintext string you want, as long as it doesn't exceed your column's length. The database doesn't know anything about HTML, it just sees a string. Your application should be what actually parses the HTML.

The actual string to insert into your DB would be something like this:

```
<p>This information is provided for the following reasons:  </p>
<ul>
    <li>The Reason 1 is following..... </li>
    <li>The Reason 2 is following..... </li>
    <li>The Reason 3 is following.....</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank's. So basically, I can do something like that when inserting the value: `<p>This information is provided for the following reasons: </p><ul><li>The Reason 1 is following.....</li><li>The Reason 2 is following....</li><li>The Reason 3 is following....</li></ul>`. And then on application level it is going to be parsed? Is there any Editor tool that I can use to test it without creating a VS project for that?

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on what you're looking for. If you just want to test whether a chunk of HTML displays correctly, you can copy/paste it into a .HTML file, then open it in your browser of choice. If that's not what you mean, you'll need to add more details about your project.

Comment: You have to use a server side technology for that.

Comment: What I need is to make sure that if I insert html code into a table's field the way I described, will it be displayed on UI the way I want.(billet pointed list)

Comment: It really depends what your UI is, and whether it supports HTML. If it's a web-app, then yeah, otherwise, it depends. Like I said, you'll need to give more details. There's not a generalized answer to that.